# mat-autocomplete the option value does not appear correctly in IOS device

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

When I select the first option in the dropdown, the option is not reflected in the field. When I select the second option then first option value appears and when selects third the second option value appears. Any suggestions as to what the problem is in my code?

This is happening only on iOS devices.Its working fine on Android and Desktop.

[image: autocomplete dropdown]

```js
emailDomains = AvailableDomains.emailDomains;

export const AvailableDomains = {
    emailDomains: [
        "hotmail.com",
        "gmail.com",
        "yahoo.com",
        "outlook.com"
    ]
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="textbox mat-form-field-invalid">
        <span class="iconError icon-alert" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Error"></span>
        <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter" formControlName="email" type="email" [matAutocomplete]="emailAutoComplete" #email>
        <mat-autocomplete #emailAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" panelWidth="auto">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let emailDomain of (email.value.endsWith('@') && email.value.split('@').length == 2 ? emailDomains : [])"  [value]="email.value + emailDomain">@{{emailDomain}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I also came across this issue in iOS. I have also tried to bind the MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent listener explicitly but it didn't work as well. The only way out I found is you need to close the keyboard panel first and then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have some auto-complete code that does work on IOS.  I compared the two and the difference I see is that I am using (optionSelected) on the mat-autocomplete tag instead of (onSelectionChange) on the mat-option tag.  Try it and see.

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="textbox mat-form-field-invalid">
    <span class="iconError icon-alert" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Error"></span>
    <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter" formControlName="email" type="email" [matAutocomplete]="emailAutoComplete" #email>
    <mat-autocomplete #emailAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" panelWidth="auto" (optionSelected)="updateForm($event,emailDomain)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let emailDomain of (email.value.endsWith('@') && email.value.split('@').length == 2 ? emailDomains : [])"  [value]="email.value + emailDomain">@{{emailDomain}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I have already tried this. It is also not working....Thanks